# How to implement SeachView in fragment without ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have `BottomNavigationBar` with 3 fragments in `MainActivity`. The `MainActivity` has no actionbar.

Now I have to implement a `SearchView` in my second fragment. I need a Searview something like WhatsApp. Currently, I have implemented it but when I click on searchview its `EditText` is not set it's height and width as `match_parent`.

I also want the back button to collapse it. How can I achieve this?

**This is my second fragment**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
xmlns:shimmer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".StudentAttendance">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:background="@drawable/bg_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
        android:text="Student Attendance"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#767a8c"
        android:fontFamily="@font/circularstdbold"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



<com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shimmer_layout"
    shimmer:duration="80"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/placeholder_list"/>
        <include layout="@layout/placeholder_list"/>
        <include layout="@layout/placeholder_list"/>
        <include layout="@layout/placeholder_list"/>
        <include layout="@layout/placeholder_list"/>
        <include layout="@layout/placeholder_list"/>
        <include layout="@layout/placeholder_list"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fitall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

**Code**

```
    final TextView txtHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search");

    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            //my code here for search
           return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your issue? is it the width of edit text. Make it match_parent

Comment: but how to set edittext to match_parent? It searchview's edittext

Comment: you need the icon in the right side it self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:background="@drawable/bg_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/not"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
            android:text="Student Attendance"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#767a8c"
            android:fontFamily="@font/circularstdbold"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Code**

```
 final android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    searchView.setQueryHint("Search");
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            txtHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is what I told you. same as above. just hide the back button.

Answer (score 0):

Just try This

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/not"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                 android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Is this you are looking?

[image]

You will get something like this . is that you want right?

Comment: I need icon on Right. Then when it clicked then its input field open with width match_parent and with left arrow at left side to collapse it again.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: My question is when i click on this searchview, it should open its EditText above my textview in toolbar with width match_parent.

Comment: Currently Its EditText have its default size

Comment: Yes Exactly i need something like this like this

Comment: Currently it is inflating over textview